# Empty result of search

Tags: youtube-data-api, google-apis-explorer

Use code:

```html
    curl \
      'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search? 
part=snippet&channelId=UCsA_vkmuyIRlYYXeJueyIJQ&eventType=live&maxResults=25&type=video&key=[MY_API_KEY]' \
      --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
      --header 'Accept: application/json' \
      --compressed
```

and in result:

```html
    {
     "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
     "etag": "\"8jEFfXBrqiSrcF6Ee7MQuz8XuAM/yWfRov5-ZkSn3_LbWvrsAvAhhaY\"",
     "regionCode": "RU",
     "pageInfo": {
     "totalResults": 0,
      "resultsPerPage": 25
     },
     "items": []
    }
```

Broke today. Yesterday everything worked correctly.

Comment: What is the expected behaviour?

Comment: There should be a list of live broadcasts on the channel